# What's a better way to parse for loads of cases than loads of individual if statements?

Tags: c++

I am working on a parser to handle hundreds of possible commands, some with their own subcommands.  I've got a tokenizer pulling out the commands into an object, but from there I just have a very very long list of if statements checking for each individual case.

Is there a better or more efficient way to check for each individual case rather than 100+ specified if statements?

For example, a command could be : A,CONFIG,SET,GARBLE,5.  This would launch into setting the config for garble to 5.  But that varies from A,CONFIG,SET,JAM,5 or another command like P,DO,ACTION which is itself another command entirely.

Right now my program covers all of these cases with individual if statements, but I feel like it's really inefficient.  If you're the last command, you're taking the longest no matter what.  Is there a better, more practical way to do this?

If you want code examples, it's really as simple as it sounds.  After getting the object full of tokenized commands, I have an absolutely huge check where it individual looks for stuff like `if (command == "P")` launch into the command handler for P commands.

Comment: Use a parser engine. Something like `boost::spirit`, `boost::wave` or flex/bison generated parsing code. I'm having a current [deja vu here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995031/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-a-text-parser-in-c) :-P ... And yes, the question is still too broad.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Uh... `boost::wave` is a C++ compliant *preprocessor* not parser.

Comment: @Borgleader THX for pointing out, I'm not actually experienced with it.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ  I disagree about the question being too broad.  It's a conceptual question regarding a faster performance compared to scaling if statements.  I gave the exact circumstances, 100 or more unique cases to parse through.  The answer was Hashing or Switch statements perform better for heavy loads, with hashing ultimately being the fastest.  Thanks for the input though.  Your link also 404's, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how complex your commands are this might be a job for a 'real' parser, either a hand rolled recursive descent parser or one built using tools like lexx and yacc.

Alternatively, if that is overkill for your use case you could use a hash table of function pointers or command objects, look up the command in the table and call the function or a method on the object to process it. That would be more maintainable than a bunch of `if` statements in my opinion.

Comment: The more modern replacements for lex and yacc are flex and bison nowadays IMHO.

Comment: I wasn't intending to specify a particular parser generator toolset, there's lots of choices these days. From the information provided in the question, I'd personally lean towards a hand rolled recursive descent parser in this case I think. For relatively simple grammars I find hand written parsers easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Arrange your commands alphabetically, then use nested case statements dealing with one letter at a time.

```
switch( command[0] ) {
case 'A': ...( code to handle commands starting with A ) ... break;
case 'B':
     switch( command[1] ) { 
      case 'A': ... ( code to handle commands BA... ) ... break;
     }
...
}
```

The switch statement optimizes the jump to the correct case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use configuration-like functionalities.

I think it's better. You would basically have to create a configuration file with a dictionary containing all of the commands and their actions, and the program would just grab the command related to the keyword.

Pseudocode:

```
{
    "COMMAND_1": function_1,
    "COMMAND_2": function_2
}
```

This is JSON-like but you can do it however you like obviously.
The functions would be basically void pointers to functions executing the related code.

Your code would basically become something like:

```
token = get_token();
if (void* command = token_in_dictionary(token, dictionary)){
    command(get_params());
}else{
    printf("Invalid token");
}
```